# Sending data (got from a SQLite query) from Flask to Javascript for creating a chart

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, flask

I have an array of data (it's a python list in my flask view) obtained after query my db.

Now I want to use those lists as labels and data in a pie chart, build with Chart.js

**Flask**

```
@app.route("/")
@login_required
def index():
[...]
    row = db.execute("SELECT DISTINCT symbol FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user_id", user_id=session['user_id'])
    labels = []
    data = []
    for l in row:
        labels.append(l.get('symbol'))
    

    rowD = db.execute("SELECT SUM(shares) AS shares FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user_id GROUP BY symbol", user_id=session['user_id'])
    for d in rowD:
        data.append(d.get('symbol'))
    return render_template("index.html", labels=labels, data=data)
```

**HTML**

```
 <canvas id = "myChart"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
                labels:  {{ labels | tojson }},
                datasets: [{
                    data: {{ data | tojson }}
            }]
          },
    });
    </script>
```

But I continue to get an error from JS (Parsing Error: Unexpected Token {) and my chart is constantly null, it doesn't appear on the page

Any help please?

I'm using some simplifications, I'm very new to programming so I'm still learning
Thanks

Comment: This is strange, on the second for loop you use "d.get('symbol')" but there is no column named symbol in that respective query. You cant inspect the HTML code on final page (CTRL + U on Firefox) to analyze how the array and objects are parsed, and put it here too to help us understand better.

Answer (score 0):

In your second for loop, you're trying to fetch a column that doesn't exists on the query:

```
rowD = db.execute("SELECT SUM(shares) AS shares FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user_id GROUP BY symbol", user_id=session['user_id'])
for d in rowD:
    data.append(d.get('symbol'))
```

This should be:

```
rowD = db.execute("SELECT SUM(shares) AS shares FROM transactions WHERE user_id = :user_id GROUP BY symbol", user_id=session['user_id'])
for d in rowD:
    data.append(d.get('shares'))
```

Comment: Yes you're right it was a transcripting error. Now I fixed it but I still getting the JS error